# how to compile parallel program on fedora 35 with mpich

Tags: fedora, mpich

I'm having problem finding the `mpicc/mpic++` compiler on fedora 35.
I already installed `mpich` with

```
sudo dnf install mpich
(some output)

[geyan@gfed ~]$ module load mpi
[geyan@gfed ~]$ which mpirun
/usr/lib64/mpich/bin/mpirun
[geyan@gfed ~]$ pwd
/home/geyan
[geyan@gfed ~]$ which mpicc
/usr/bin/which: no mpicc in (/usr/lib64/mpich/bin:/home/geyan/.local/bin:/home/geyan/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin)
[geyan@gfed ~]$ cd /usr/lib64/mpich/
[geyan@gfed mpich]$ ls
bin  lib
[geyan@gfed mpich]$ cd bin/
[geyan@gfed bin]$ ls
hydra_nameserver  hydra_pmi_proxy  mpiexec          mpiexec.hydra  mpivars
hydra_persist     mpichversion     mpiexec.gforker  mpirun         parkill
```

When `mpi` is loaded, I can find `mpirun/mpiexec` but couldn't find the compiler. What should I do? Or there the wrapped compiler is different on fedora?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that `mpich` provides a compiler, it provides the libraries you need when `MPI` programs execute and some utilities, such as `mpirun`, you may find useful.  But not a compiler.

Comment: Try `dnf install mpich-devel` and see if `mpicc` is found then.  For future similar issues, `dnf provides '*/mpicc'`, and similar commands are useful to identify which package you may want to install.